# javascript prototype method not getting result

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, javascript-objects

```
var Person = function(name,age,job){
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
     this.job = job;
}

var dependar = new Person('Dependar',20,'Student');
```

now that we have created our constructor and all.

I'm trying to use prototype .

```
Person.prototype.city = 'Delhi';
```

we have attached new var city to the constructor and all the elements created with it(var dependar)

dependar.city is working properly, it is assigned to 'Delhi'

but when I try to attach a method using prototype

```
  Person.prototype.dob = function(){
         this.dob = 2017 - this.age;
    }
```

but when I enter
dependar.dob;

it is displaying the function not the result

```
function (){
    this.dob = 2017 - this.age;
}
```

What is going wrong? please help

Comment: You would need to *call* the method... Or use a getter.

Comment: this has nothing to do with ES6?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I enter dependar.dob;it is displaying the function not the result.

---

**REASON:**
This is because you have defined it as:

```
Person.prototype.dob = function(){
         this.dob = 2017 - this.age;
    }
```

which is assigning (2017 - this.age) to this.dob .But dob is not defined in the function.

**What you can do:**

Return value dob directly.

```js
var Person = function(name, age, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.job = job;

}

var dependar = new Person('Dependar', 20, 'Student');
Person.prototype.dob = function() {
  return (2017 - this.age);
}

console.log(dependar.dob());
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I'm curious when we type console.log(dependar.dob);
it displays the function that we have assigned, but when we enter
console.log(dependar.dob());
it returns the value.
may I know the reason why?

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: using  () invokes the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the console, if you type `dependar.dob`, or if you use a `console.log(dependar.dob)`, you are getting what you asked for -- the value of `dob`, which is a FUNCTION and so it does its best to display the contents of that value - the function source code.

To get the function value you need to *execute* the function, which means `dependar.dob()` -- note the use of the parens.  Those cause the function to execute.